# Cosine similarity between item descriptions using scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I am using python 2.7 and scikit-learn to find cosine similarity between item descriptions.

A have a `df`, for example:

```
items    description

1fgg     abcd ty
2hhj     abc r 
3jkl     r df
```

I did following procedures:

1) tokenizing and stemming each `description`

2) transform the corpus into vector space using `tf-idf`

3) calculated `cosine distance` between each description text as a measure of similarity. `distance = 1 - cosinesimilarity(tfidf_matrix)`

My goal is to have a similarity matrix of  `items` like this and answer the question like: "What is the similarity between the items `1ffg` and `2hhj` :

```
        1fgg    2hhj    3jkl
1ffg    1.0     0.8     0.1
2hhj    0.8     1.0     0.0
3jkl    0.1     0.0     1.0
```

How to get this result? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy array to create the matrix and then add index and head to create a dataframe.

Assume you have a list of descriptions: `descriptions = ['abc', 'bcd', 'etc' ...]` and corresponding tf-idf matrix. (row number corresponds description number)

You want to create an empty numpy array of shape NxN, where `N = len(words)`

`distance_matrix = np.zeros((N,N))`

Then you need to fill it with actual distances:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        distance_matrix[i,j] = cosine_distance(tf_idf[i,:], tf_idf[j,:])
```

You can create dataframe with

`pandas.DataFrame(distance_matrix, index = items_list, columns = items_list)`

Comment: Hi @greenwolf, can I ask something again. Is it possible to add more info in calculating distances. For example, given `rating`, `item`, `description` and `user` calculate item (e.g.movie) description distances only which user rated?

Comment: Question is not very clear, but if I got this right, you can add some conditions into the loop, and calculate distances only when needed (e.g. if you want to get distance matrix for special user reviews, you just can fill distances between unrated items with zeros).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've added this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561658/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-with-tf-idf-to-evaluate-similarity-of-items-o Nobody replied though.

Comment: @greenwolf, Suppose I want to make a list from the dataframe that you suggested in the answer. I want something like `index, column_name, cosine_distance` for every entry in the dataframe in the form of a list or a dataframe. How can I get that?